# Azure Storage connection string How to implement to applicate

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

I need to create access to the Azure storage from application. Application requires storage, where to put file. This code below, I am trying to put where application requires path to store file. Am I doing right? How can I implement this into XML of Application, so then it starts to write files to cloud storage.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name= "DefaultConnection" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=;/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what kind of application you are developing? Is this a Web Application. As you mention you can put it on `web.config` / `App.config` for normal app

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#set-up-your-development-environment) for example.

In your app.config, please add:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key" />
</appSettings>
```

And in your code, please use:

```
// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

Then you can take use of azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

if you login to the Blob image storage on Azure. it should populate the connection string by default. PFB Reference

[image]